# MS Word dialog "may contain features that are not compatible with Plain Text format"

Tags: microsoft-word

MS Word 2016 on W10

Trying to save a document as text keeps prompting:

> may contain features that are not compatible with Plain Text format. Do you want to save the document in this format?*

I have added this registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Word\Options
DisableSaveAsLossWarningOpenDocumentText value 1
```

but the dialog is not getting disabled.

Wondering if anyone has any suggestions. Thx. Tosh.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the issue with MS Word 2016 MSO (16.0.9126.2336) 64-bit.
I performed an update and now the version is showing MS Word for Office 365 MSO (16.0.10730.20264) 64-bit. 
This appears to have helped. I am no longer seeing the dialog box.